# Жадность регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь выцепить содержимое div блоков при помощи регулярных выражений.
Допустим есть вот такая ситуация

```
text = "<div class="text-underline"><u>Программист</u></div>"
```

Написал такое регулярное выражение

```
text = re.findall(r'>.{1,}?<', text)
```

Ожидаю увидеть на выходе `>Программист 1C 8<` но получаю `><u>Программист 1C 8<`

Comment: Попробуйте исключить скобки: `>[^<>]{1,}?<`

Comment: Это сработало. Спасибо!

Comment: Для парсинга xml/html лучше использовать парсеры xml/html, а не регулярки или явится ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5909792 :)

Answer (score 0):

Регулярка в любом случае старается найти наиболее раннюю позицию, с которой есть совпадение. А нежадные режим уже после этого будет стараться взять как можно меньше.

Если необходимо что-то исключить, то стоит это явно и запрещать: `>[^>]+?<`

```js
var text = `<div class="text-underline"><u>Программист</u></div>`

console.log(text.match(/>[^>]+?</))
```

А в более сложных случаях надо запрещать через `(?:(?!что-то).)+`.