# Regex для поиска чего-либо внутри тега

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть некоторая строка по типу

```
<a class="link" href="./img/photo.jpg" download="">Фото</a>
```

искомая строка заключена в тег

Использую:

```
pattern = r'(<a.+/a>)'
```

столкнулся с конструкцией:

```
<a> </a>
<p> </p>
<a> </a>
```

на выходе получаю строку с ДВУМЯ открывающими и закрывающими тегами и текстом между ними:

```
**<a** class="link" href="./img/photo.jpg" download="">Фото**</a>*<p class="link">id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ</p>*<a** class="link" href="./img/tochno.txt" download="">Документ**</a>**
```

Вопрос: как сделать поиск по шаблону НЕ жадным?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1390898/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy
по вашему совету, использую:\
    pattern = r'<a.+/a>[^<]' 
место стыка выглядит: 
    download="">Фото</a><p class=
результат негативный. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
a = """**<a** class="link" href="./img/photo.jpg" download="">Фото**</a>*<p class="link">id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ</p>*<a** class="link" href="./img/tochno.txt" download="">Документ**</a>**"""

s = re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^<>]+(?=</)', a)
print(s)
# ['Фото**', 'id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ', 'Документ**']
```

Без регулярок

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
a = """**<a** class="link" href="./img/photo.jpg" download="">Фото**</a>*<p class="link">id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ</p>*<a** class="link" href="./img/tochno.txt" download="">Документ**</a>**"""

soup = Soup(a, 'html.parser')
print(*soup.stripped_strings, sep='\n')
```

output

```latex
**
Фото**
*
id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ
*
Документ**
**
```

Comment: у меня вопрос к вам.
Почему в данном pattern = '<a.+a[>]?', после использования участок download="">Фото</a><p class= НЕ РАЗДЕЛЯЕТСЯ('><'). Ведь явно указано, что закрывающая тег скобка - '>' должна быть одна - '?'.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, потому, что в выражении `<a.+a[>]?` знак вопроса допускает отсутствие `>`. тоесть фактически это читается как "символ `>` может быть 1 либо отсутствовать". По другому Ваше выражение можно записать так `<a.+a[>]{0,1}` возможно так нагляднее

Comment: я поставил явный ограничитель '<a.+a[>]{1}'
почему по прежнему выходная строка остается такой же?
Иными словами я хочу найти первый закрывающий тег </a> и остановиться на нем.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, `<a.+?>` вот так попробуйте. Я не сразу понял чего вы пытаетесь добиться

Comment: Последний вопрос буквально. Ваш паттерн верен. До ужаса прост и мал.
Но я не понимаю почему он правильный. Почему берет первую >, а не как у меня было наверху
<a> ... ... ... </a>... ... ...</a> ?

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, знак вопроса `?` делает не жадными `.+` и `.*`  тоесть `.+?` и `.*?` являются "не жадными"

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, вот тут почитайте. Очень толковый справочник по основным библиотекам https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-re-python/

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, не за что. Отметьте ответ как принятый.